# Micronaut doesn't return default HTTP error representation for Flux return types

Tags: java, project-reactor, micronaut, micronaut-rest

I have simple Micronaut controller with 2 similar `GET` methods which return different reactive types.

```java
@Controller
public class MyController {
    
    @Get(uri = "/a", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_STREAM)
    public Flux<MyPojo> getA() {
        return Flux.just("Hi")
                .flatMap(s -> Mono.error(new HttpStatusException(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, s)))
                .map(o -> new MyPojo());
    }

    @Get(uri = "/b", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_STREAM)
    public Mono<MyPojo> getB() {
        return Mono.just("Hi")
                .flatMap(s -> Mono.error(new HttpStatusException(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, s)))
                .map(o -> new MyPojo());
    }
                
}
```

Now, if I invoke endpoint `/b` I'll get HTTP 400 with default error representation [`io.micronaut.http.hateoas.JsonError`](https://docs.micronaut.io/2.5.3/api/io/micronaut/http/hateoas/JsonError.html) provided by [`io.micronaut.http.server.exceptions.HttpStatusHandler`](https://docs.micronaut.io/latest/api/io/micronaut/http/server/exceptions/HttpStatusHandler.html) which is desired and perfect.

```
{
  "message": "Bad Request",
  "_embedded": {
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Hi"
      }
    ]
  },
  "_links": {
    "self": {
      "href": "/b",
      "templated": false
    }
  }
}
```

However, if I'll invoke endpoint `/a` I'll get HTTP 500 error without any body. Log file reports following error:

```
2022-01-12 00:45:31.385 ERROR [default-nioEventLoopGroup-2-2] i.m.h.netty.stream.HttpStreamsHandler    : Error occurred writing stream response: Hi
io.micronaut.http.exceptions.HttpStatusException: Hi
    at com.example.MyController.lambda$getA$6(MyController.java:199)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(FluxFlatMap.java:386)
    at io.micronaut.reactive.reactor.instrument.ReactorSubscriber.onNext(ReactorSubscriber.java:57)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$ScalarSubscription.request(Operators.java:2398)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onSubscribe(FluxFlatMap.java:371)
    at io.micronaut.reactive.reactor.instrument.ReactorSubscriber.onSubscribe(ReactorSubscriber.java:50)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxJust.subscribe(FluxJust.java:68)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Flux.subscribe(Flux.java:8468)
    ...
```

which seems correct...

The question is - how to get correct HTTP code (400) and default error representation (`JsonError`) in case of endpoint `/a`?

Answer (score 1):

the `/a` endpoint indicates streaming because you're returning a non single publisher type. Streamed responses are handled differently and we switch to the mode of writing the response when the error is encountered. At this point it isn't feasible to go back to create another response because an OK response has already been sent down the Netty pipeline.

See https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-core/issues/5581

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. However it dosn't explain HTTP 500, according your words it should be HTTP 200 with error message emitted. Another curious thing is how flux will be handled in case  of error in the middle of stream. Imagine you're returning flux of objects and in the middle you get exception for particular element. My expectation is that if I have something like `.onErrorContinue` in my pipeline, it should emitt valid elements then error and continue with valid elements.

Comment: It returns a 500 because we delay emission of the 200 response until at least 1 item gets emitted

Comment: Can you please point me to some Micronaut documentation (even feature definition pages or anything raw/internal), so I can understand expected behaviour for error handling cases related to reactive return types? I still feel that it doesn't work right